# Multitenant GraphQL Server

Tags: graphql, fastify

We are exploring GraphQL server for our SaaS multi-tenant services where we have multiple microservices / services behind a single multi-tenant GraphQL server. Now we have a situation where client's can extend their GQL schema through our preferred mechanism;

so is there any way in which we can still have a single GQL server that will be serving multiple GQL schemas through multiple endpoints?

Or we will have to deploy each client's GQL server + schema in totally separate server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple schemas served by the same application. GraphQL Schemas can even be built at runtime. Maybe you could even use the fastify GraphQL middleware. For more complicated things, you will probably have to build your own middleware, but this would be totally possible.

Creating multiple endpoints with different schemas is easy. You can simply mount more GraphQL middlewares:

```js
for (const customer of customers) {
  app.register(graphqlFastify, { 
    prefix: '/' + customer.name + '/graphql', 
    graphql: {
      schema: customer.schema,
    },
  });
}
```

But this probably does not scale very well. You might want to use a route with a parameter instead and then you execute the GraphQL function yourself. Maybe, you could combine this with [graphql-helix](https://github.com/contrawork/graphql-helix):

```js
import { graphql } from 'graphql';

fastify.get('/:username/graphql', (request, reply) => {
  const { queryString, variables, operationName } = getGraphQLParams(request);
  const schema = getUserSchema(request.username);

  return graphql(schema, queryString, rootVal, context, variables, operationName);
});
```

All code above is not tested and I don't know fastify nearly enough to create working code. But I hope this shows the possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, it gave me some ideas; let me try out. So the first option you mentioned above isn't scalable since it host all the customer's schemas into server memory, while the 2nd option bind them at runtime? But I guess, we would need to store schema in-memory or cache like Redis for 2nd option as well for all practical purposes?

Comment: In the first solution, all schemas will be statically bound to a route. In the second example, schemas will be created at request time, which is probably a huge performance hit. The thing is: What you are trying to do is not really a standard use case of GraphQL. Depending on your use case, you could go away from graphql-js execution at all and develop your own execution engine.

Comment: I visited your link graphql-helix, it looks like it binds the query with the schema at runtime, if the schema is locally available the it shouldn’t take much time, it will be just a decision which one to choose based on each customer. 

Here is example of runtime binding between request and schema, assuming schema is already ready, this shouldn’t be that costly operation right?

const result = await processRequest({
      operationName,
      query,
      variables,
      request,
      schema,
    });

Comment: If you have the schema already available in memory, this should not be more expensive. IMO, one should not just theoretically reason about performance, just try it out.

Comment: Tried the first option, that doesn't work, 

FastifyError: The decorator 'graphql' has already been added! mercurius doesn't support deploying multiple schemas on the same server; since there is no optional path/prefix in all decorators. I will try 2nd option, is there any example of 2nd option with Fastify?

Comment: The 2nd option did worked for me, thank you!

Comment: Great to hear that!